# How to interpret the little-$o$ notation in this definition of the Poisson process?

Tags: probability, notation, asymptotics

In the book Probability and Random Processes by Grimmett and Stirzaker, a Poisson process is defined to be any process $(N(t))_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$ satisfying following three properties:

$\hspace{20pt}$(a) $N(0) = 0$ and $s<t\Rightarrow N(s)\leq N(t)$

$\hspace{20pt}$(b) $\mathbb{P}\left(N(t+h)=n+m|\hbox{ }N(t) =n\right) =\begin{cases}
o(h) & \text{if } m>1,\\
\lambda h + o(h) &\text{if } m=1,\\
1 - \lambda h + o(h) & \text{if }m=0\\
\end{cases}$

$\hspace{20pt}$(c) if $s<t$ then $N(t)-N(s)$ is independent of the times of emissions on $[0,s]$.

I am having problems with understanding the meaning $o(h)$ in (b), so my question is:

> How do we interpret $o(h)$ in this definition?

I know $o(h)$ in the classical sense is supposed to be just a function such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{o(h)}h=0$. But here, $o$ is used three times and I suspect it has a different meaning each time. (Since otherwise, we would necessarily have $o\equiv0$.)

So, I did some thinking and reinterpreted (b) to read:

$\hspace{20pt}$(b') There exist functions $o_1, o_2, o_3$, such that for $i=1,2,3$:$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{o_i(h)}h=0$$
$\hspace{38pt}$and
$$\mathbb{P}\left(N(t+h)=n+m|\hbox{ }N(t) =n\right) =\begin{cases}
o_1(h) & \text{if } m>1,\\
\lambda h + o_2(h) &\text{if } m=1,\\
1 - \lambda h + o_3(h) & \text{if }m=0.\\
\end{cases}$$

But I am completely confused about the order of quantifiers in this statement (which is why I left this rewording a bit vague). Should the functions $o_1,o_2,o_3$ be the same for all $t,n$ and $m>1$? (That is: should we take a separate function $o_m$ for each m? Or even a separate function $o_{t,n,m}$ for each triple $(t,n,m)$?)

> Does this even matter or are these definitions miraculously equivalent?

I would really like to know what exactly it is this definition is trying to define. Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the convention for using little-o notation is that every $o(\cdots)$ in an equation can stand for a *different* function that is eventually smaller than the identity.

Also, usually the precise function is allowed to depend in arbitrary ways on anything that is *not* mentioned in the "\cdots".

Consider, for example the not unusual definition of the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ being the (unique) $\lambda$ such that $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+\lambda h + o(h)$. Here it is implicit that the $o(\cdots)$ function can depend on $x_0$ but not on $h$.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, $o$ can be a different function $o_{t,m,n}$ for every triple $(t,m,n)$? Ok, this pretty much completely answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would interpret it (absent some very specific indications to the contrary).

Answer (score 2):

Once you've found exact formulas for the Poisson process, it could help your intuition to  go back and write the functions explicitly. I will re-index the $o$ functions to match $m$
as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(N(t+h)=n+m|\hbox{ }N(t) =n\right) =\begin{cases}
1 - \lambda h + o_0(h) & \text{if }m=0\\
\lambda h + o_1(h) &\text{if } m=1,\\
o_m(h) & \text{if } m>1,\\
\end{cases}
$$

From the explicit formulas, we have 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
o_0(h)&=&e^{-\lambda h}-1+\lambda h\\
o_1(h)&=&\lambda h(e^{-\lambda h}-1)\\
o_m(h)&=&(\lambda h)^m\, e^{-\lambda h}/m! \ \mbox{ for } m>1\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

As you see, these functions depend on $m$ and $\lambda$, but not $n$ or $t$.

Comment: However, the fact that they don't depend on $n$ or $t$ is an "accidental" consequence of all of the definitions together. It is not something one should have been able to read _syntactically_ off part (b) of the definition.

Comment: Also, oughtn't there be an $m$ somewhere in your expression for $o_1$? Surely the probability of the process going from $0$ to $m$ in time $h$ cannot be the same for every $m\ge 2$.

Comment: @Henning Quite right. It is because the Poisson process is homogeneous in space and time. Things won't always work out so well.

Comment: @Hennig Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed helps my intuition. (And justifies my suspicion of things being miraculously equivalent. =))